# How to recursive regexp rename double dashes

Tags: regex, batch-rename

I am using Wordpress Eazyest gallery to create 2000 galleries. Some files have double or triple dashes in filenames. For instance: abc---def.jpg These files are uploaded via FTP.

On Wordpress admin and front end HTML's they get replaced, this file gets the name abc-def.jpg so they become broken links / src's.

Is there a way I can replace all ---'s or --'s in a folder with a single - character using SSH? I am on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

To match/change that pattern within a single directory it should be as simple as

```
rename -- 's/-+/-/' *.jpg
```

(replace one or more consecutive dashes with a single dash) but do a dry-run first by adding the -n and -v flags

```
rename -nv -- 's/-+/-/' *.jpg
```

If there are multiple instances of the multiple dashes in a single name (e.g. abc---def--ghi.jpg) then you will need to add a `g` (global) switch

```
rename -- 's/-+/-/g' *.jpg
```

If you need to change names in gallery subdirectories recursively then you could use the rename command as an `exec` action to a `find` command e.g.

```
find /path/to/dir -name '*.jpg' -exec rename -nv -- 's/-+/-/g' {} +
```

or, if your remote shell supports the `globstar` shell option you could try making the rename command act recursively on its own by using a glob like `**/*.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

1. `ssh` into the Ubuntu box which you installed Wordpress on;
2. `cd` into the main directory containing all the galleries;
3. run `find -iname '*--*' -exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(echo {} | tr -s '-')"' \;`.

Comment: Please include an explanation of your suggested solution with the intent to educate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only one set of `---` or `--` in each file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -e

## Substitute /path/to/folder for the root folder
if cd /path/to/folder
then
    find . -name '*---*.jpg' -exec bash -c 'file={}; mv -v "${file}" "${file/---/-}"' ';'
    find . -name '*--*.jpg' -exec bash -c 'file={}; mv -v "${file}" "${file/--/-}"' ';'
fi
```

`ssh` into the machine then run the code above, replacing `/path/to/folder` for the root folder with all the files.